# How to set different warehouse in one sell order in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

Let's suppose I have make sale order of product `Ram` and `Graphic card`.
But condition is Ram is deliver in **New warehouse** and Graphic card is deliver in **Old warehouse**
How can it is possible to make such a scenario in odoo.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? May you share your efforts and codes ?

Comment: I am not done any coding it is my requirement to do this scenario. currently I am not do any stuff regarding to this because I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Did you solve your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one warehouse_id field in sale.order.line, After that you can select warehouse Sales Order Line wise.

One Odoo community module is available for Version V7/V8/V9.

**https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/sale_sourced_by_line/**